# how to prevent chrome from changing tabs when you click and drag a link to a new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I like to do a Google search, and then click and drag only some of the answers to new Chrome tabs, and finally select the tab I want to look at.  Internet Explorer does it this way.

How can I set Chrome to do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Just <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> click on the link - it will open in a new tab without changing the current the tab. This works on a Mac, so on a PC perhaps you get the same effect with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.